# How java hashmap convert to list<String, Double>?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, hashmap

I want convert variable map

```
HashMap<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

in `List<Pay>`

```
List<Pay> res = new ArrayList<Pay>();
```

, where POJO `Pay` have variables `String` and `Double`.
How I make conversion from `HashMap<String, Double>` to `List<Pay>`???

Comment: Loop through the keys and values of the map and create Pay objects out of them. What have you tried?

Comment: Post `Pay`. How an we help you without that?

Comment: I smell a Java 8 solution here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suppose to use something like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    res.add(new Pay(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue));
}
```

First you get a set of Entry-Objects out of your HashMap. Then you iterate over this Set, extract the key and the value out of each Entry, use them to create Pay objects and place them in you ArrayList at the end.

Comment: Thank you! I also wrote, but replaceresult.add(new PayForBank(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())); wrote result.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code sample - First read hashmap using its keys and set key and values to the Pay class variables and then save all Pay objects in the list.

```
    public static void main (String[] args){

    HashMap<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    map.put("A",5.0);

    Pay pay=new Pay();

    List<Pay> res = new ArrayList<Pay>();

    for(String key:map.keySet()){
        System.out.println(key);
        pay.setName(key);
        pay.setAmount(Double.parseDouble(map.get(key).toString()));

        res.add(pay);
    }

    System.out.println(res);

}


class Pay{

private String name;
private double amount;

public void setName(String key) {

    this.name=key;
}

public void setAmount(double value) {

    this.amount=value;
}

 public double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}


 public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Pay [name=" + name + ", amount=" + amount + "]";
}



}
```

Output :

```
[Pay [name=A, amount=5.0]]
```